# Modify request parameter with servlet filter

Tags: java, servlet-filters

An existing web application is running on Tomcat 4.1.  There is an XSS issue with a page, but I can't modify the source.  I've decided to write a servlet filter to sanitize the parameter before it is seen by the page.

I would like to write a Filter class like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;

public final class XssFilter implements Filter {

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException
  {
    String badValue = request.getParameter("dangerousParamName");
    String goodValue = sanitize(badValue);
    request.setParameter("dangerousParamName", goodValue);
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
  }

  public void destroy() {
  }

  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
  }
}
```

But `ServletRequest.setParameter` doesn't exist.

How can I change the value of the request parameter before passing the request down the chain?

Comment: HttpServletRequestWrapper has lot of APIs defined.I am trying to understand each and every API meaningfully.Javadoc is not helping  to understand APIs like 'userinRole','getPrincipal'etx.,Where exactly I can get some help?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

As you've noted `HttpServletRequest` does not have a setParameter method. This is deliberate, since the class represents the request as it came from the client, and modifying the parameter would not represent that.

One solution is to use the `HttpServletRequestWrapper` class, which allows you to wrap one request with another. You can subclass that, and override the `getParameter` method to return your sanitized value. You can then pass that wrapped request to `chain.doFilter` instead of the original request.

It's a bit ugly, but that's what the servlet API says you should do.  If you try to pass anything else to `doFilter`, some servlet containers will complain that you have violated the spec, and will refuse to handle it.

A more elegant solution is more work - modify the original servlet/JSP that processes the parameter, so that it expects a request *attribute* instead of a parameter. The filter examines the parameter, sanitizes it, and sets the attribute (using `request.setAttribute`) with the sanitized value. No subclassing, no spoofing, but does require you to modify other parts of your application.

Comment: HttpServletRequestWrapper is wonderful; I never knew it existed.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the attribute setting alternative! Saw sample code using request and response wrappers in Head First Servlets and JSPs and couldn't believe the spec pushes people to go about things that way.

Comment: I had reached out with my values in controller and I have set tha parameter(email and pass) ... now how can i replace the values in my servlet                                                    `<property name="username" value="somemail@gmail.com" /> //Change email on logging in
    <property name="password" value="*********" />//Change Password on logging in`

Answer (score 83):

For the record, here is the class I ended up writing:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;

public final class XssFilter implements Filter {

    static class FilteredRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

        /* These are the characters allowed by the Javascript validation */
        static String allowedChars = "+-0123456789#*";

        public FilteredRequest(ServletRequest request) {
            super((HttpServletRequest)request);
        }

        public String sanitize(String input) {
            String result = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
                if (allowedChars.indexOf(input.charAt(i)) >= 0) {
                    result += input.charAt(i);
                }
            }
            return result;
        }

        public String getParameter(String paramName) {
            String value = super.getParameter(paramName);
            if ("dangerousParamName".equals(paramName)) {
                value = sanitize(value);
            }
            return value;
        }

        public String[] getParameterValues(String paramName) {
            String values[] = super.getParameterValues(paramName);
            if ("dangerousParamName".equals(paramName)) {
                for (int index = 0; index < values.length; index++) {
                    values[index] = sanitize(values[index]);
                }
            }
            return values;
        }
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(new FilteredRequest(request), response);
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }
}
```

Comment: You might also need to account for the getParameterMap method.  Maybe throw and unsupported exception just so no components use the method and skip the sanitize logic.

Comment: Good point, Tom.  In this particular case, I checked and found it wasn't being called, but I should have added that for completeness and for the next person's sake.  Thanks!

Comment: It looks like I'm that next person, Jeremy. I found this post when looking for options to modify data being passed from an outside application to a third-party servlet. In my case, the servlet wasn't calling HTTPServletRequest.getParameter(), getParameterMap(), or even getAttribute() to get the request data, so, through trial and error, I determined that the servlet was calling HTTPServletRequest.getInputStream() and getQueryString(). My advice to anyone attempting this task for closed servlets is to wrap every single accessor in HTTPServletRequest in order to understand what's really going on

Comment: For SrpingMVC, you will need to override getParameterValues() to fool Spring.  RequestParamMethodArgumentResolver.resovleName() uses that method, so you will get MissingServletRequestParameterException without overriding. Tested on Spring Boot 1.2.6 with spring-web 4.1.7.

Answer (score 11):

Write a simple class that subcalsses `HttpServletRequestWrapper` with a getParameter() method that returns the sanitized version of the input. Then pass an instance of your `HttpServletRequestWrapper` to `Filter.doChain()` instead of the request object directly.

Answer (score 4):

Based on all your remarks here is my proposal that worked for me :

```
 private final class CustomHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private final Map<String, String[]> queryParameterMap;
    private final Charset requestEncoding;

    public CustomHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
        queryParameterMap = getCommonQueryParamFromLegacy(request.getParameterMap());

        String encoding = request.getCharacterEncoding();
        requestEncoding = (encoding != null ? Charset.forName(encoding) : StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    private final Map<String, String[]> getCommonQueryParamFromLegacy(Map<String, String[]> paramMap) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(paramMap);

        Map<String, String[]> commonQueryParamMap = new LinkedHashMap<>(paramMap);

        commonQueryParamMap.put(CommonQueryParams.PATIENT_ID, new String[] { paramMap.get(LEGACY_PARAM_PATIENT_ID)[0] });
        commonQueryParamMap.put(CommonQueryParams.PATIENT_BIRTHDATE, new String[] { paramMap.get(LEGACY_PARAM_PATIENT_BIRTHDATE)[0] });
        commonQueryParamMap.put(CommonQueryParams.KEYWORDS, new String[] { paramMap.get(LEGACY_PARAM_STUDYTYPE)[0] });

        String lowerDateTime = null;
        String upperDateTime = null;

        try {
            String studyDateTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse(paramMap.get(LEGACY_PARAM_STUDY_DATE_TIME)[0]));

            lowerDateTime = studyDateTime + "T23:59:59";
            upperDateTime = studyDateTime + "T00:00:00";

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Can't parse StudyDate from query parameters : {}", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }

        commonQueryParamMap.put(CommonQueryParams.LOWER_DATETIME, new String[] { lowerDateTime });
        commonQueryParamMap.put(CommonQueryParams.UPPER_DATETIME, new String[] { upperDateTime });

        legacyQueryParams.forEach(commonQueryParamMap::remove);
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(commonQueryParamMap);

    }

    @Override
    public String getParameter(String name) {
        String[] params = queryParameterMap.get(name);
        return params != null ? params[0] : null;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
        return queryParameterMap.get(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap() {
            return queryParameterMap; // unmodifiable to uphold the interface contract.
        }

        @Override
        public Enumeration<String> getParameterNames() {
            return Collections.enumeration(queryParameterMap.keySet());
        }

        @Override
        public String getQueryString() {
            // @see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/35831692/9869013
            // return queryParameterMap.entrySet().stream().flatMap(entry -> Stream.of(entry.getValue()).map(value -> entry.getKey() + "=" + value)).collect(Collectors.joining("&")); // without encoding !!
            return queryParameterMap.entrySet().stream().flatMap(entry -> encodeMultiParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), requestEncoding)).collect(Collectors.joining("&"));
        }

        private Stream<String> encodeMultiParameter(String key, String[] values, Charset encoding) {
            return Stream.of(values).map(value -> encodeSingleParameter(key, value, encoding));
        }

        private String encodeSingleParameter(String key, String value, Charset encoding) {
            return urlEncode(key, encoding) + "=" + urlEncode(value, encoding);
        }

        private String urlEncode(String value, Charset encoding) {
            try {
                return URLEncoder.encode(value, encoding.name());
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot url encode " + value, e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("getInputStream() is not implemented in this " + CustomHttpServletRequest.class.getSimpleName() + " wrapper");
        }

    }
```

*note : 
queryString() requires to process ALL the values for each KEY and don't forget to encodeUrl() when adding your own param values, if required*

*As a limitation, if you call request.getParameterMap() or any method that would call request.getReader() and begin reading, you will prevent any further calls to request.setCharacterEncoding(...)*

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (changing a parameter from the HTTP request in the Filter). I ended up by using a `ThreadLocal<String>`. In the `Filter` I have:

```
class MyFilter extends Filter {
    public static final ThreadLocal<String> THREAD_VARIABLE = new ThreadLocal<>();
    public void doFilter(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
        THREAD_VARIABLE.set("myVariableValue");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

In my request processor (`HttpServlet`, JSF controller or any other HTTP request processor), I get the current thread value back:

```
...
String myVariable = MyFilter.THREAD_VARIABLE.get();
...
```

Advantages:

- more versatile than passing HTTP parameters (you can pass POJO objects)
- slightly faster (no need to parse the URL to extract the variable value)
- more elegant thant the `HttpServletRequestWrapper` boilerplate
- the variable scope is wider than just the HTTP request (the scope you have when doing `request.setAttribute(String,Object)`, i.e. you can access the variable in other filtrers.

Disadvantages:

- You can use this method only when the thread which process the filter is the same as the one which process the HTTP request (this is the case in all Java-based servers I know). Consequently, this **will not work when**

  - **doing a HTTP redirect** (because the browser does a new HTTP request and there is no way to guarantee that it will be processed by the same thread)
  - **processing data in separate threads**, e.g. when using `java.util.stream.Stream.parallel`, `java.util.concurrent.Future`, `java.lang.Thread`.
- You must be able to modify the request processor/application

Some side notes:

- The server has a Thread pool to process the HTTP requests. Since this is pool:

  1. a Thread from this thread pool will process many HTTP requests, but only one at a time (so you need either to cleanup you variable after usage or to define it for each HTTP request = pay attention to code such as `if (value!=null) { THREAD_VARIABLE.set(value);}` because you will reuse the value from the previous HTTP request when `value` is null : side effects are guaranteed).
  2. There is no guarantee that two requests will be processed by the same thread (it may be the case but you have no guarantee). If you need to keep user data from one request to another request, it would be better to use [`HttpSession.setAttribute()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html)
- The JEE [`@RequestScoped`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/context/RequestScoped.html) internally uses a `ThreadLocal`, but using the `ThreadLocal` is more versatile: you can use it in non JEE/CDI containers (e.g. in multithreaded JRE applications)

Comment: Is it really a good idea to set a parameter in the thread's scope? Will multiple requests ever see the same thread? (I assume not)

Comment: Is it a good idea = yes (but you need to know what you're doing, anyway the JEE `@RequestScoped` does internally the same). Will multiple request see the same thread = no (or at least you have no guarantee). I've edited the answer to precise these points.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i ended up doing

```
//import ../../Constants;

public class RequestFilter implements Filter {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            CustomHttpServletRequest customHttpServletRequest = new CustomHttpServletRequest((HttpServletRequest) servletRequest);
            filterChain.doFilter(customHttpServletRequest, servletResponse);
        } finally {
            //do something here
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

     public static Map<String, String[]> ADMIN_QUERY_PARAMS = new HashMap<String, String[]>() {
        {
            put("diagnostics", new String[]{"false"});
            put("skipCache", new String[]{"false"});
        }
    };

    /*
        This is a custom wrapper over the `HttpServletRequestWrapper` which 
        overrides the various header getter methods and query param getter methods.
        Changes to the request pojo are
        => A custom header is added whose value is a unique id
        => Admin query params are set to default values in the url
    */
    private class CustomHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
        public CustomHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
            super(request);
            //create custom id (to be returned) when the value for a
            //particular header is asked for
            internalRequestId = RandomStringUtils.random(10, true, true) + "-local";
        }

        public String getHeader(String name) {
            String value = super.getHeader(name);
            if(Strings.isNullOrEmpty(value) && isRequestIdHeaderName(name)) {
                value = internalRequestId;
            }
            return value;
        }

        private boolean isRequestIdHeaderName(String name) {
            return Constants.RID_HEADER.equalsIgnoreCase(name) || Constants.X_REQUEST_ID_HEADER.equalsIgnoreCase(name);
        }

        public Enumeration<String> getHeaders(String name) {
            List<String> values = Collections.list(super.getHeaders(name));
            if(values.size()==0 && isRequestIdHeaderName(name)) {
                values.add(internalRequestId);
            }
            return Collections.enumeration(values);
        }

        public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames() {
            List<String> names = Collections.list(super.getHeaderNames());
            names.add(Constants.RID_HEADER);
            names.add(Constants.X_REQUEST_ID_HEADER);
            return Collections.enumeration(names);
        }

        public String getParameter(String name) {
            if (ADMIN_QUERY_PARAMS.get(name) != null) {
                return ADMIN_QUERY_PARAMS.get(name)[0];
            }
            return super.getParameter(name);
        }

        public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap() {
            Map<String, String[]> paramsMap = new HashMap<>(super.getParameterMap());
            for (String paramName : ADMIN_QUERY_PARAMS.keySet()) {
                if (paramsMap.get(paramName) != null) {
                    paramsMap.put(paramName, ADMIN_QUERY_PARAMS.get(paramName));
                }
            }
            return paramsMap;
        }

        public String[] getParameterValues(String name) {
            if (ADMIN_QUERY_PARAMS.get(name) != null) {
                return ADMIN_QUERY_PARAMS.get(name);
            }
            return super.getParameterValues(name);
        }

        public String getQueryString() {
            Map<String, String[]> map = getParameterMap();
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (String param: map.keySet()) {
                for (String value: map.get(param)) {
                    builder.append(param).append("=").append(value).append("&");
                }
            }
            builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1);
            return builder.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Regular Expression** for Sanitization. Inside filter before calling **chain.doFilter(request, response)** method, call this code.
Here is Sample Code:

```
for (Enumeration en = request.getParameterNames(); en.hasMoreElements(); ) {
String name = (String)en.nextElement();
String values[] = request.getParameterValues(name);
int n = values.length;
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++) {
     values[i] = values[i].replaceAll("[^\\dA-Za-z ]","").replaceAll("\\s+","+").trim();   
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not modify the original request parameters this way, but on a copy.

Answer (score -3):

Try `request.setAttribute("param",value);`. It worked fine for me.

Please find this code sample:

```
private void sanitizePrice(ServletRequest request){
        if(request.getParameterValues ("price") !=  null){
            String price[] = request.getParameterValues ("price");

            for(int i=0;i<price.length;i++){
                price[i] = price[i].replaceAll("[^\\dA-Za-z0-9- ]", "").trim();
                System.out.println(price[i]);
            }
            request.setAttribute("price", price);
            //request.getParameter("numOfBooks").re
        }
    }
```