# Is there a way to get post parameters from a http request in a filter but keep the input stream intact for servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters, sitebricks

I am trying to fix a bug in sitebricks where it consumes the input stream in of the data of all servlets even those not using site bricks.

HiddenMethodFilter.java line:66

```
String methodName = httpRequest.getParameter(this.hiddenFieldName);
```

See http://code.google.com/p/google-sitebricks/issues/detail?id=45

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can provide your own request, see [Modify request parameter with servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413129/modify-request-parameter-with-servlet-filter).

Furthermore may be extending the wrong sitebricks filter might be easier than chaining.

Comment: the new request would need to encapsulate duplicate contents of POST in form of some byte array InputStream, right?

Comment: That seems a bit scary because we could be copying unbounded array into memory

Comment: No, `HttpServletRequestWrapper` wraps the original request.

Comment: https://github.com/dhanji/sitebricks/pull/14 Here is the fix I came up with. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's still not really obvious to me how HttpServletRequestWrapper prevents the input stream to be read to get the parameters in a POST request. The question you are linking to describes a completely different problem.

Comment: @Usman: The fix you committed does not change anything. Without subclassing HttpServletRequestWrapper and adding your own behaviour, all methods will simply delegate to the original request, which was passed to the constructor.

Comment: @jambjo you are basically right, but suppressing parameters and such would be feasible. Also since no deep copying is involved, it is feasible for this use-case. True, I am glad a better solution was found.

Answer (score -2):

Obivously not, since the servlet container is required to read and consume the data in the InputStream before it is able to give you the request parameters. The other way around if you consume the InputStream first, the container won't have access to the request parameters later.

Why can't you fix the bug using the suggestion in the linked issue suggesting to configure the HiddenMethodFilter only for the URLs related to Site Bricks?

Comment: Sitebricks uses annotations to determine which urls it serves so that information is hard to get in the filter.

Comment: Why can't you check the URL in the filter before invoking getParameter, so that the HttpServletRequest is left untouched for requests to URLs not handled by SiteBricks?

Comment: Although it may be possible to inject the list of URL handled by sitebricks into the filter I haven't found a way to do it yet. ps I did not down vote your answer, this is the ideal solution.