# JSP and send object

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

I have problém with send servlet to JSP

I have "web.xml".

```
    <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>optimalizace5</display-name>
    <servlet-name>optimalizace5</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
BucketServlet2
 </servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>optimalizace5</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/optimalizace5</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

and BucketServlet2:

```
public class BucketServlet2 extends HttpServlet{

@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

     request.getSession().setAttribute("vysledek_list", "10101101");
     getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/optimalizace4.jsp").forward(request, resp); 
     super.doPost(request, resp);
    }
}
```

and JSP:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Optimalizační úlohy</title>
</head>
<body>
<FORM action="/Eliminace_kosiku/optimalizace5" method="post">

Data:

<%=request.getParameter("vysledek_list")%>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

For send from JSP to servlet is working. But send from servlet to JSP not working. I dont know, what is wrong??

Comment: Plz, specify your question. `from servlet to JSP not working`  is ambiguous.

Comment: <%=request.getParameter("vysledek_list")%> return null. And return must be "10101101".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getParameter` take the URL parameter value. At `Servlet` you set the value at session, so, you should use `session.getAttribute` instead of `getParameter`

```
<%=request.getSesstion().getAttribute("vysledek_list")%>
```

Another point, As you use forward method at Servlet so `request.setAttribute` enough to pass value to JSP page. You should not store temporary value(i.e. same request) at `session`. So, set the value at `request` instead of `session` like below.

```
 request.setAttribute("vysledek_list", "10101101");
```

Comment: I cant. "Vote up requires 15 reputation" :(

Comment: @user3640712, there is a check mark below the down-vote arrow, you can click on it.

Answer (score 1):

You are putting value in `session`, not in request object.

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("vysledek_list", "10101101");
//          ^ setting attribute in session object.
```

So you need to take out value from session object in jsp.

Session is implicit object in jsp, so you can directly use it like

```
<%=session.getAttribute("vysledek_list")%>
```

**Note:** Don't forget to remove it from session if you don't need it further.

```
<%session.removeAttribute("vysledek_list");%>
```

---

**Another approach:** With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8551357/3898076).

You can just change below line in your code of `doPost` method

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("vysledek_list", "10101101");
```

with

```
request.setAttribute("vysledek_list", "10101101");
```

**Update :** 
Addition in second approach, in jsp use `getAttribute` method instead of getParameter method.

```
<%=request.getAttribute("vysledek_list")%>
```

Comment: I am try it, but still is variable null.

Comment: Did you try both approach?