# Add new parameters when forwarding a request from a Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

JSP can add new parameters to the HTTP request when forwarding using one or more `<jsp:param>` tags:

```
<jsp:forward page="newPage.jsp">
  <jsp:param name="param1" value="value1" />
  <jsp:param name="param2" value="value2" />
</jsp:forward>
```

How parameters can be added when forwarding from a Servlet?

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/newPage.jsp");
// TODO: how to add parameters?
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8551357/10606400) answer your question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can concatenate parameters to URL as query parameters

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/newPage.jsp?param1=value1&param2=value2");
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to create new `HttpServletRequest` because parameters are immutable.
You can do it with `HttpServletRequestWrapper` for example.