# Add/Edit request parameter to Jetty request

Tags: java, http, servlets, jetty

I am interfacing some legacy code with a new system and I have to edit a HTTP request.

I am using Jetty to launch an embedded webserver from our application and have wrapped our webapp with the a `org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler` class.

I can successfully manipulate the URI but I cannot find a way to edit the request parameters.
I tried wrapping the request in `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper` and overriding the `getParameters()` method as per this thread:

[Modify request parameter with servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413129/modify-request-parameter-with-servlet-filter)

However this did not work as Jetty casts the request object at some point and it fails.

Does anyone know of a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up retrieving the necessary data from the `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` object and then building the required URL with the edited parameters etc, then calling

`response.sendRedirect(newUrl);`

on the `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse` which worked perfectly.