# handle duplicate values for Spring @RequestParam

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a Spring 3.2 Controller with basic request mappings like

```
@RequestMapping("/action")
public String action(@RequestParam("param") String param) {
    //do stuff...
    return "view";
}
```

This controller handles links created by non-technical business users. Sometimes the users mess it up and create links with duplicate parameters, e.g.,

```
www.example.com/action?param=value&param=value
```

The parameter is an exact duplicate and probably a copy/paste error.

My problem is that Spring is concatenating these dupes together, so that the url above will give `"value,value"` for `param`, when I want only `"value"`.

**What is a good way to detect and handle these duplicates?**  I know I could change all my `@RequestParam`s to `List<String>`s and go from there, but that's a whole lot of boilerplate over dozens of request mappings.

Ideally there would be a way to intercept and modify the url parameters before Spring attempts to bind them -- but only for this controller.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `?param=value&param=value` is not the same as `?param=value` only. So if Spring did that "merging" in any way, it would be an invalid behavior. So, yeah, you have to implement it yourself. Be it through a new `...ArgumentResolver` or `...Interceptor`.

Comment: A `HandlerInterceptor` was my first thought too, but you can't modify parameters from there.

Comment: Yeah, it is not possible to *change* the attributes. To achieve what you want, you have to, in the interceptor, wrap the `HttpServletRequest` in a `HttpServletRequestWrapper` (see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413129/modify-request-parameter-with-servlet-filter ).

Comment: If you mean a servlet `Filter` rather than a Spring `HandlerInterceptor` then yes. I feel like a solution should exist higher than the servlet level though.

Comment: In my case for spring-web 5.3.25 it's duplicated for no reason...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that I can register a custom String property editor to do this.

```
class DuplicateParameterReducingPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    Object value;

    @Override
    public void setValue(Object value) {
        if (value instanceof String[]) {
            String[] strings = (String[])value;
            Set<String> unique = Sets.newHashSet(strings);
            this.value = unique.toArray();
        } else {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        this.value = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsText() {
        return value.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue() {
        return value;
    }

};
```

I added this to my controller:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {

    PropertyEditor stringEditor = new DuplicateParameterReducingPropertyEditor();
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, stringEditor);
}
```

So whenever Spring encounters a `@RequestParam`-annotated String method argument, the `PropertyEditor` is invoked to transform the incoming data if needed.  In the case of duplicate parameters, Spring passes a `String[]` of the values to the property editor `setValue`, which I can then manipulate.

This does have the results I am looking for.  I'm not sure of all the implications of this, though, so I can't endorse it as good solution yet.  Not having to alter any handler method signatures is a big plus though.

Answer (score 1):

A good idea would be to extend `AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver` with your own strategy. Then the strategy could be used wherever you deem necessary.

This strategy only works for Spring 3.1+ which is not a problem for you since you are using Spring 3.2

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking :)

Comment: Could you provide an example or link to documentation?  I know how to register a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` but I'm not sure how to override the default `@RequestParam` resolver.

Comment: I don't think you can override the default behavior... What I had in mind was to write a new resolver with it's own annotation. However I would be very happy to see some example of overriding the default behavior!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue in Spring boot. Eventually I came up with this solution using converter, in case it helps anyone.

This method should be added as part of your WebMvcConfigurer class.

```
@Override
public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
    // Duplicate query parameters converter
    registry.addConverter(new Converter<String[], String>() {
        public String convert(String[] arr) {
            return arr[arr.length - 1];             // Return the last value
        }
    });
}
```