# request parameters got duplicated when forwarded between two tomcats

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, query-string

We have a Controller running on tomcat 8.5.32 which receives a POST request with query params
/{path_param}/issue?title=4&description=5
request body is empty

Then controller redirects this request to Spring Boot microservice with tomcat 9.0.27.
At line

```
CloseableHttpResponse result = httpClient.execute(request);
```

`request.getURI().getQuery()` equals`&title=1&description=2`

But when it arrives to microservice parameters are duplicated (title=[4,4]&description=[5,5]).

This is the code which redirects request to microservice

```
  private static <T, U> T executePostRequest(String url, U body, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, Function<String, T> readValueFunction) {

    try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build()) {
        URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(url);
        httpServletRequest.getParameterMap().forEach((k, v) -> Arrays.stream(v).forEach(e -> uriBuilder.addParameter(k, e)));
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(uriBuilder.build());
      

        CloseableHttpResponse result = httpClient.execute(request);
        String json = EntityUtils.toString(result.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

        handleResultStatus(result, json);

        return readValueFunction.apply(json);
    } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
        ...
    }
}
```

I found that there was similar issue with [jetty](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/2074) and it was fixed but did not find anything related to tomcat - and how it can be fixed.
I saw also [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817430/handle-duplicate-values-for-spring-requestparam) whith suggestion how to handle duplicated parameters in spring boot but i am wondering if anyone else experienced same issue and how did you resolve it if yes.

Comment: Can you add the code used to forward the request to you question?

Comment: added a code example

Comment: The code you posted works as expected. Maybe you have other elements in the system (reverse proxies, rewrite valves), which duplicate the elements of your request?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, it's a feature present in every servlet container.

The Servlet API does not require for the request parameters to have unique names. If you send a `POST` request for `http://example.com/app/issue?title=1&description=2` with a body of:

```
title=3&description=4
```

then each parameter will have multiple values: `title` will have values `1` and `3`, while `description` will have values `2` and `4` in that order:

> Data from the query string and the post body are aggregated into the request
> parameter set. Query string data is presented before post body data. For example, if
> a request is made with a query string of a=hello and a post body of a=goodbye&a=
> world, the resulting parameter set would be ordered a=(hello, goodbye, world).

([Servlet specification](https://javaee.github.io/servlet-spec/downloads/servlet-4.0/servlet-4_0_FINAL.pdf), section 3.1)

If you want to copy just the first value of the parameters use:

```java
httpServletRequest.getParameterMap()//
                  .forEach((k, v) -> uriBuilder.addParameter(k, v[0]));
```

Comment: Thank you Piotr foryour response,
 body is empty in our case, at the line 
CloseableHttpResponse result = httpClient.execute(request);
request.getURI().getQuery() contains &title=1&description=2

 but when it arrives to microservice, values are duplicated.