# Prevent concatenation of parameters if sent twice

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, rest

I have some rest API

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getSomething")
public String getSomething(@RequestParam(value = "name") String name)
```

Caller to the API can provide multiple instances of the name parameter

/getSomething?**name**=something&**name**=somethingElse

In the API code the name variable will be received as "something,somethingElse"

Is there a way yo prevent this behavior ?

accept only one "name" parameter?

or return "400" "bad request" for such a case?

Thanks

Comment: I am just guessing here, but I think it is Http protocol issue rather then spring boot. So, I would try to see if you have ',' in your input - fail it. but then what if ',' is actually part of the input...

Comment: well as you said, the input may contain ","

Comment: Are you looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22817430/handle-duplicate-values-for-spring-requestparam ?

Comment: For permanent solution, refere as  @VoiceOfUnreason mentioned, but to stop the bleeding you can do something like this -> if(Arrays.asList(name.split(",")).size()>1) { throw exception }