# request.setParameter in JSP

Tags: jsp, getparameter

I tried to do in JSP action will determine the value of a text field and saw no action `request.setParameter`. I tried to search online solutions and unfortunately I did not find.

I'd love to help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want to sanitize a full HTTP request (though this should not utterly be required in your use-case)? There is no such method as `request.setParameter()` associated with an `HttpServletRequest` class (This is deliberate). If you want to modify request parameters then, you need to customize/sanitize `HttpServletRequest` itself by wrapping it around `HttpServletRequestWrapper` basically by using a `Filter`. [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1413129/1391249).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input is sent to whatever the your forms 'action' attribute is.
Lets say you have the following code

```
<form action="login.jsp" method="post">
    <lable><b>Username</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="username">
    <label><b>Password</b></label>
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

This means that, when your form is submitted, your login.jsp receives a POST request with those variables, these are accessible via the [request (HttpServletRequest)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) object

For example, with the above code, you could use `request.getParamater("username")` to get the input supplied in the username field.

Comment: First of all, thank you. I was going to **setParameter** not to getParameter. You have an idea how can I do it?

Comment: Set parameter is for changing pre-existing or new parameters, usually you would do that in a filter for thigs like input validation

Comment: Yes, I would like to change pre-existing parameters. What is the code for that?

Comment: Just use the setParameter method with a key and value, am i not understanding something?

Comment: There setParameter to jsp?

Answer (score 0):

request.setParameter - is relevant when you're putting some parameter inside the HTML header. 
In order to set the text inside the text field you should have a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp

Comment: Yes, but how do you determine the value only with jsp?