# Facing issue while resolving cross site scripting issue

Tags: java, xss

I was preventing my application from cross site scripting defect. I have done the validation part for all the fields present in my application, but I don't know how to prevent this defect if someone injects the code in the url, please help me how to get rid of this defect.
Eg:
Script:

```
javascript:alert(document.cookie)
```

like if we inject the above code in the url we can get the username and the session id after logout.

Please suggest me the solution.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413129/modify-request-parameter-with-servlet-filter. Also I recommend to use proven libraries for sanitization and don't write validation code yourself: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_Encoder_Project

Answer (score 1):

html decoding/encoding cant help in this, I tested this on most of the web application (like Atlassian JIRA, Slack) all were allowing this and it was being printed in html page. This tag will only work i following cases:
if it is being printed 
in href attribute-

```html
<a href="javascript:alert(document.cookie)">Test</a>
```

in Onclick attribute

```html
<a href=# onclick="javascript:alert(document.cookie)" >test</a>
```

So make sure that you are not printing anything directly in href or onClick attribute, if you are doing than add any filter there which can manually detect javascript or dont forgot to append http:// before the link.

Answer (score 0):

Someone entering `javascript:alert(document.cookie)` in the address bar is *not* a vulnerability.

If an attacker put a href in their website linking to `javascript:alert(document.cookie)` then it would simply show the cookies on the attacker's site.

Only the user can enter the code in their own browser. This is known as [Self-XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-XSS).

If this is not what you mean, please update your question with an example of a working URL (you could change your domain to `example.com` for privacy), and then add a comment to let me know and I'll update my answer to help.