# How to wrap request and response to generate customized request and response using servlet filters?

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters

How to wrap request and response to generate customized request and response using servlet filters?

I want to write a filter that will be invoked before the request reaches to the servlet and want to do some modification in the request and then want to forward to the servlet.

Similarly, I want to modify the servlet generated response using the filter and want to forward the customized response to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to extend HttpServletRequestWrapper and HttpServletResponseWrapper and override respective methods. Please refer to below links for examples:

[Modify request parameter with servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413129/modify-request-parameter-with-servlet-filter)

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0400__Servlet/Filterthatusesaresponsewrappertoconvertalloutputtouppercase.htm

Hope this helps!