# Ability to modify income request URL HttpServletRequest to perform encoding?

Tags: java, servlets, encoding

I have a URL coming in that is not in a good format (contains brackets) `[]` I want to intercept the incoming request from the `HttpServletRequest` object and modify this URL to encode it, then continue the flow of the function.

for example: `https://my-website.com/getData/?when[name="john"]&location[place="starbucks"]`

I want to handle the encoding of this string once it hits my function.

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413129/modify-request-parameter-with-servlet-filter) could help. Replacing strings with its encoded version is trivial `[ -> %5B , ] -> %5D`.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz I need to modify the income servlet object to ensure the changes are effective, that's the problem

Comment: but not the servlet itself, just the request, correct?

Comment: That's correct, but I'm wondering how to modify the request and have it persist in that same incoming object if that makes sense

Comment: Extend `HttpServletRequestWrapper` and override methods such as `getParameter(...)` and `getQueryString()` to handle the encoding.  As @LuisMuñoz suggested, create a filter to handle the incoming request.    Within the filter, create an instance of your wrapper, and pass your wrapper instance as part of the filter chain.  When your function invokes `request.getParameter("when")`, the `request` will be your wrapper (or possibly another wrapper but that should not matter).

Comment: @AndrewS ok, is it possible to modify a uriInfo object as well? I call getRequestUri on the object, but it breaks

Comment: What does _break_ mean?  Are you encoding just the query part, and not the whole URL? Add more code (or perhaps post a different question).

Comment: String url = uriInfo.getRequestUri().toString(); breaks because there is an illegal character in the url. I want to modify so the illegal character is gone. IllegalArgumentException