# Override @QueryParam annotation to trim whitespaces

Tags: java, annotations, jersey, jax-rs, dropwizard

Currently I'm working with Dropwizard and want to trim whitespaces from query parameters that are passed in, that match a specific key (in my case, `query`). I couldn't find documentation on how to do this.

The closest solution I've found, apart from manually trimming the whitespace, is to create a new annotation, however I'm trying to avoid changing dozens of endpoints, and would rather override the base annotation to apply the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a jetty servlet filter to modify that query param, see this thread for an example:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1422202/52954

Then register that filter:

```
environment.servlets().addFilter("Custom-Filter-Name", new MyCustomFilter());
```