# How to map undefined amount of path parameters to request parameters in Ocpsoft Rewrite?

Tags: jsf, dynamic, path-parameter, ocpsoft-rewrite

Currently I´m trying the following JSF - Lib:

https://www.ocpsoft.org/rewrite/examples/

I have the following issue:

I have a page:
/page.jsf

In my page I have more then only one parameter.
E.g. I have:
- parameter1
- parameter2

```
String parameter1 = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
                    .getRequestParameterMap().get("parameter1");

            String parameter2 = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap()
                    .get("parameter2");
```

Currently I understood I can add this in my UrlConfigProvider class:

.addRule(Join.path("/page/{parameter1}").to("/portal/mypage.jsf")
                    .withInboundCorrection())

This is working for one parameter.

But how can I do this for multiple parameter, so the URL is then:
/page/{parameter1}/{parameter2}
....

Any ideas?

Comment: This might help you: https://www.ocpsoft.org/opensource/how-to-safely-add-modify-servlet-request-parameter-values/

Comment: thank you, but should be the URL rewrite rule?

Comment: just to make it clear: you want to rewrite `/page/p1/p2/p3/ ...` to page `/portal/mypage.jsf?p1=?&p2=?&p3=?& ...` with a dynamic number of parameters?

Comment: yes, correct.... How do I have to adjust the rule then? .addRule(Join.path("/page/{parameter1}").to("/portal/mypage.jsf") .withInboundCorrection())

Answer (score 0):

The rewrite API doesn't bring a native solution for this problem.

---

#### Kick-Off Example

```java
.addRule()
.when(/* your condition */)
.perform(new HttpOperation() {
    @Override
    public void performHttp(HttpServletRewrite httpServletRewrite, EvaluationContext evaluationContext) {
        // this is the default wrapper
        HttpRewriteWrappedRequest request = ((HttpRewriteWrappedRequest) httpServletRewrite.getRequest());

        // get the uri (example: '/index/p1/p2')
        String uri = httpServletRewrite.getRequest().getRequestURI();

        // split by slash
        String[] split = uri.split("/");

        // this is example specific
        // split value 0 is empty and split value 1 is the page (e.g. 'index')
        // for every folder increment the index
        // for '/pages/index' the start index should 3
        for (int i = 2; i < split.length; i++) {
            String s = split[i];

            // the request parameter is by default an immutable map
            // but this returns a modifiable
            request.getModifiableParameters().put("prefix" + (i - 1), new String[]{s});
        }
    }
});
```

---

#### Explanation

The only important piece is the `HttpOperation`. By default the `ServletRequest` is wrapped in a `HttpRewriteWrappedRequest`.

The default `HttpServletRequest` doesn't allow to change the parameters once they were initialized. The method [`getParameterMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap()) returns an immutable map.

`getParameterMap()` of the `HttpRewriteWrappedRequest` also returns an immutable map. But `getModifiableMap()` returns obviously a modifiable map.

The rest should be self-explanatory.

---

#### See Also

[Ocpsoft: How to modify parameters](https://www.ocpsoft.org/opensource/how-to-safely-add-modify-servlet-request-parameter-values/)

[Modify request parameter with servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413129/modify-request-parameter-with-servlet-filter)